# Automatically show pictures

Tags: vb.net

I have the flowing code set up to where I can insert a number into cells A1:J1 from a number that is from 1 to 10.  I then have 10 pictures that correspond to a number from 1 to 10.  So if I insert the number 1 into A1, the image associated with it shows up below it.  That goes for all cells in the range A1:J1.  Now my problem is that if I enter 1 in A1 then in cell C1 enter another 1 the image moves from below cell A1 to below C1.  I want it to be like if I had all number ones from the range A1:J1 then the same picture would show up below all of those numbers.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Me.Pictures.Visible = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:J1")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each rngCell In Me.Range("A1:J1")
            On Error Resume Next
            Me.Pictures("BldgA" & rngCell.Value).Visible = True
            Me.Pictures("BldgA" & rngCell.Value).Top = rngCell.Offset(1).Top
            Me.Pictures("BldgA" & rngCell.Value).Left = rngCell.Offset(1).Left
            Err.Clear: On Error GoTo -1: On Error GoTo 0
        Next rngCell
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert a new picture into the appropriate cells instead of just moving the same one around (which is why your code won't allow duplicate pictures).  [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/visualfoxprogeneral/thread/78f86ad4-2da7-410b-9290-b61cdd2d069c/) may be some help to you for inserting pictures into an Excel spreadsheet.